# Site not available after move-spsite

Tags: powershell, content-database, move

A site collection isn't available after moving it to another content database.
Errors: **HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 08:47:25 GMT Connection: close** 
OR **File not found**
How can we solve the issue?
Regards Michael

Answer (score 0):

After running the cmdlt `move-spsite` you need to make sure to run an IIS Reset on your servers to clear all the applications pools cache that still thinks the site is in the old database.

Comment: IISRESET was done. The site doesn't occure in the old whether in the new content database.

Comment: Did you do an iisreset on all the servers after the move?